# How can I input() using TeleBot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I was wondering if i can make `input()` using TeleBot dependency.

e.g. console way:

```
POL = float(input("Enter your POL: ))
```

Is there a way to do using Telebot, like:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Enter your POL")
## Get message.text into POL variable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, there isn't a direct way of doing this, but you can look at the message that the user has replied to from

```
replied_message = message.reply_to_message.message_id
```

If it matches the id of the message that you sent then that would be the reply to your message. You can get the id of your sent message from

```
sent_message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Enter your POL")
sent_message_id = sent_message.message_id
```

Comment: can you please describe more about it?

Comment: Yeah, sure. When the user replies to the message, the message object that gets passed as an argument into the message handler function would store the id of the message that they replied to, so you can use this to keep track of the message that the user has replied to. Another way to work around this is to just keep a record of the last message that you sent the user and match the user's next reply, in which case, the user doesn't have to reply to any message, which might be similar to input()

Comment: So you could create a message handler just looking out for the message with the reply_to_message.message_id attribute that is the same as your sent_message_id or one that just catches the next message after your "Enter your POL" message to catch the input from the user

Answer (score 1):

```py
import telebot


TELEGRAM_TOKEN = '<TOKEN>'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
user_register_dict = {}

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message , 'now send your name')
    user_register_dict[message.chat.id] = {}
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message , start_step2)

def start_step2(message):
    user_register_dict[message.chat.id]['name'] = message.text
    bot.reply_to(message , 'now send your age')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message , start_step3)

def start_step3(message):
    user_register_dict[message.chat.id]['age'] = message.text
    bot.reply_to(message , 'your name is {} and you are {} years old!'
    .format(user_register_dict[message.chat.id]['name'] , 
    [message.chat.id]['age'] ))

    start(message = message)
```

Create a `dict` for handling the data, which is important because if you use `lists` (eg.) maybe 2 people starts to register in same time and data gonna crash!

Difference between `create bot.register_next_step_handler` (line 13 for example) with connect directly for example `start(message = message)` in end line is in `register_next_step_handler` bot waits for new message and when received puts it in message and start defection but in direct start defection bot doesn't wait for user message, and start defection with current message `start(message = message)`